# Deltas and CC Basis Swaps

Tags: swaps, delta, hedge

How do I calculate the dollar impact of basis change for a portfolio of cross currency basis swaps which hedged loans/bonds?

I am thinking it might have something to do with delta and tenors but I am not quite sure of the concept.

Thanks

Comment: How are you valuing the cross-currency basis swap portfolio? By bootstrapping a basis curve?

Answer (score 1):

Take the weighted average tenor of your book. Weights being the notional of the non usd leg. That is very roughly your duration, which gives you your risk !  Ps i assume all the trades are on the same currency pair